# Finding a way to determine the Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I want to (manually) determine the Laurent series of

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}$$

at it's two singularities.

(Please note that I'm not just interested in the result itself – I already [checked Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laurent%20series%201%2F%281-z-z%5E2%29&dataset=) on how the Laurent series of $f$ looks like. I want to understand how one would actually determine that result. I've also found a number of other threads where the Taylor expansion at $z = 0$ for this function was dealt with, which I found quite interesting too, but I didn't see how that helps me with the Laurent expansion.)

My attempt so far: so first I have to figure out the singularities itself. Considering that $1 -z - z^2$ has the roots $z_{1, 2} = -\frac{1}{2} ± \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$, these two are singularities. Considering $1 -z -z^2$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, $z_{1, 2}$ are poles of order $2$, I would say. (Which gives me that $c_{n} = 0$ for $n < -2$ in the laurent series, I believe?)

I don't really know how to continue from there, though. Could partial fraction decomposition be helpful?

Comment: Did you try plugging $z+z^2$ into the expansion for $\frac1{1-x}$?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't think of that so far. Would it be that simple if I know the expansion for $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Comment: Of course you will get the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Power_series) (from Gregory Grant's suggestion every term will be given by the sum of the two earlier terms).

Comment: @moran You should commit the expansion of $\frac1{1-x}$ to memory, it's the most  basic of all taylor series and it's the basis of so many other formulas.  It's $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac1{1-x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. Perform a partial fraction decomposition:
$$
\frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}=\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac1{ z+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2}-\frac1{z+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2}\right)
$$ then use the classic Taylor series expansion of a geometric series.